# LIKE in "where" LINQ statement causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

`ProductModel.cs`:   (class)

```
public List<Product> GetSearchedProduct (string Name)
{
    try
    {
        using (garagedbEntities db = new garagedbEntities())
        {
            List<Product> products = (from x in db.Products
                                      where x.Name LIKE @txtSearch
                                      select x).ToList();
            return products;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`search.aspx`:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

 <br />

<asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts" runat="server">
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This is my `search.aspx` file. Actually I want to get the name of the `product` from `TextBox` then pass it to method which retrieves the `products`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linq you should use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
List<Product> products = (from x in db.Products
                           where x.Name.Contains(Name)
                           select x).ToList();
```

**Edit**: To use method you should create a new instance of `ProductModel` and then call the `GetSearchedProduct` method and send the `txtSearch` as a parameter to it. Like this:

```
protected void btnSearch_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductModel pr = new ProductModel();
    var result = pr.GetSearchedProduct(txtSearch.Text);
}
```

Comment: @AliIrfan I'm guessing you want to use the `Name` parameter you are passing into your method there.  Note that `Contains` will be the same as putting a % wildcard at the beginning and end of the string in a SQL query.

Comment: Great !  it works !  THANKS ALOT MATE